# Best method of assigning NULL value to SqlParameter

Tags: c#, null, sqlparameter

I have a number of optional input parameters I am using in a C# class method. Since the optional syntax creates a value of '0' when the parameter is not used, the SQL insert command I call in the method winds up inserting as such. However, I need the command to insert a NULL value instead of a 0 when the parameter is not being used. What is the best way to accomplish this without using a large amount of 'if' statements?

Below is the code I am referring to. Is there syntax/a command of some kind that will allow me to specify a NULL value in the SqlParameter declaration?

```
public int batchInsert
(
    int id, 
    int outcome, 
    int input = 0, 
    int add = 0, 
    int update = 0,
    int delete = 0,
    int errors = 0, 
    int warnings = 0
)
{
    string sts;
    if (outcome == 0)
    {
        sts = "S";
    }
    else if (outcome == 1)
    {
        sts = "W";
    }
    else
    {
        sts = "E";
    }

    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(this.connString);
    SqlParameter runId = new SqlParameter("@runId", id);
    SqlParameter endTime = new SqlParameter("@endTime", DateTime.Now);
    SqlParameter status = new SqlParameter("@status", sts);
    SqlParameter sqlInput = new SqlParameter("@itemsRead", input);
    SqlParameter sqlAdd = new SqlParameter("@add", add);
    SqlParameter sqlUpdate = new SqlParameter("@update", update);
    SqlParameter sqlDelete = new SqlParameter("@delete", delete);
    SqlParameter sqlError = new SqlParameter("@errors", errors);
    SqlParameter sqlWarning = new SqlParameter("@warnings", warnings);
    SqlParameter result = new SqlParameter("@outcome", results[outcome]);
    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(insertCommand(), sqlConn);
```

Comment: Do you have cases in which zero is a legitimate value to write in the database table?

Comment: If you use nullable types in C# you can use this syntax to substitute a database `NULL` for a C# `null`: `myVariable ?? (object)DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, for the value of the parameter, just use `DBNull.Value`.  For example:

```
SqlParameter sqlError = 
    new SqlParameter("@errors", errors == 0 ? (object)DBNull.Value : errors);
```

Or write a little helper:

```
private object ValueOrDBNullIfZero(int val) {
   if ( val == 0 ) return DBNull.Value;
   return val;
}
```

Then:

```
SqlParameter sqlError = 
    new SqlParameter("@errors", ValueOrDBNullIfZero(errors));
```

Comment: For some reason I only saw the "Yes, for the value of the parameter, just use DbNull.Value", and not the example. Thx!

Comment: @georgem - Yup, I'm thinking that should work as well, although most of the time ADO.NET is smart enough to convert a `null` value to `DbNull.Value` on its own, so I'm not sure that would be necessary.

Comment: thanks, work perfect for my needs. don't forget to allow null value on table column.

Comment: Thank you.  Precisely what I needed for a piece of code I'm working on.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to check each parameter value and use `DBNull.Value` send null. We have an extension method off `object` to make this a little easier.

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static object OptionalParam<T>(this T value, T optionalValue = default(T))
    {
        return Equals(value,optionalValue) ? (object)DBNull.Value : value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var sqlInput = new SqlParameter("@itemsRead", input.OptionalParam());
```

Or if you want to consider a non-default, arbitrary value as the default value:

```
var sqlInput = new SqlParameter("@itemsRead", input.OptionalParam(-1));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest way to assign a Null value to sql parameter

```
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", string.IsNullOrEmpty(comment) ? (object)DBNull.Value : comment);
```

Comment: Another option is to use `Convert.DBNull` instead of `(object)DBNull.Value`.  
Example (with a nullable int):  
`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optionalParam", id.HasValue ? id.Value : Convert.DBNull);`

Answer (score 2):

with small helper class we can create extenction method to add DBNull.Value to sqlparameter

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace System.Data.SqlClient
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods 

    {



        public static SqlParameter AddParameter(this SqlParameterCollection parms, SqlParameter param)
        {
            if (param.Value == null)
            {
                param.Value = DBNull.Value;
                return parms.Add(param);
            }
            else
            {
                return parms.Add(param);        
            }

        }
}
```

usage

```
SqlParameter _FraudPackageID = new SqlParameter("@FraudPackageID", System.Data.SqlDbType.BigInt);
 _FraudPackageID.Value = FraudPackageID;
 _FraudPackageID.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

_cmd.Parameters.AddParameter(_FraudPackageID);
```

if you assign or pass null as value to sqlparameter this extenction method will automatically converts it to DBNull and reassign to the sqlparameter.

so no need to worry about what the values we are passing dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Nullable(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) structure available. It'll let you only set values if you have them, and your SQL Command objects will recognize the nullable value and process accordingly with no hassle on your end.

Answer (score 0):

short syntax!

```
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter{SqlValue=username ?? (object)DBNull.Value,ParameterName="usuario" }  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another clear way to set a null datetime parameter when necessary

```
if(obj.myDate == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    aCommand.Parameters.Add("dateParameter", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    aCommand.Parameters.Add("dateParameter", SqlDbType.Date).Value = obj.myDate ;
}
```